# Structurally Replace Intellij Jsp

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, structural-search

I want replace structurally an attribute html with its value. The example is the following. I want replace this instruction

```
<IMG SRC="<%=immagineGes%>" title="<%=toolTipGes%>">
```

with

```
<IMG SRC="<%=immagineGes%>" title="<%=GestioneString(toolTipGes, format)%>">
```

Which is the correct syntax in intellij? Thanks in advance for availability

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could simply use the exact same text as patterns. Search pattern:

```
<IMG SRC="<%=immagineGes%>" title="<%=toolTipGes%>">
```

Replace pattern:

```
<IMG SRC="<%=immagineGes%>" title="<%=GestioneString(toolTipGes, format)%>">
```

But use `HTML` as File type.